# Manage Azure App service deployment center FTP users

Tags: ftp, deployment, credentials, azure-web-apps

So as Azure admin of my company I was trying to create an overview of what contributors have created FTP Credentials for app services. It's fine that they create these credentials however I would like to find a way to either report what accounts have been created and take note when someone creates a new account.

I've tried to enable diagnostic logs on app services like:
AppServiceHTTPLogs
AppServiceConsoleLogs
AppServiceAppLogs
AppServiceFileAuditLogs
AppServiceAuditLogs
AppServiceIPSecAuditLogs
AppServicePlatformLogs

Which seems to log some type of user interaction with the app service but seems to have no FTP related information what so ever. If anyone has any idea on how to pull more information on this sort of data I would love to know, with Powershell would work as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, App Service's storage is a networking drive that is mapped to the App Service. And the FTP is another service that allow you to access and manipulate data in that drive. So the App Service and FTP will have no idea about each other.